# When I tap buy button in market how does wallet check my allowance instantly?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, metamask, cryptokitties, transferfrom

On CrytpoKitties, when I tap the buy button in a market, MetaMask comes up and shows if I can buy or not based on allowance instantly. How is this possible? Is it making query? Is it included in kitty's contract?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Metamask is checking if you have approved the tokens to be spent by the Cryptokitty smart contract.

If the dapp is transferring tokens on the user's behalf (i.e. calling `transferFrom()`), then the dapp must check if the user has the proper `allowance`.

In order to use `transferFrom()`, the user must *allow* a contract to spend tokens on their behalf. To do this, the user must first `approve()` a certain amount of tokens that they are willing to the let the dapp transfer. The dapp must confirm that the user has an adequate `allowance()` before calling the `transferFrom()` function, or else it will fail.

Comment: I had never sent any tx like approve. After login via metamask, I tapped the buy button, then checking allowance comes up.